# Node.js Two-Factor Authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I am working on a personal program using node.js that uses authentication for Steam app specifically. The login reads the username and password from an external .txt file and it works using array positioning, split by a ‘:’ (colon). Now this is where I need help. With some accounts Steam uses a two factor code that is randomly generated by time on a mobile app or by email. At this time, I have my program so it checks to see if the account has the authentication code enabled and if it does I have it prompt to manually put in the appropriate two factor code. I know that there is a way to incorporate my program to pull this authentication code and put it in without having the user to do so manually but I don’t know where to start.

**Problem:** I want the program to pull a randomly generated code and automatically set it in without having to do anything manual.

Code is as follows:

```
else if (eresult === Steam.EResult.AccountLoginDeniedNeedTwoFactor)
 {
    login.two_factor_code = readline.question(`[${param[0]}] Mobile auth code: `);
    client.disconnect();
    client.connect();
      }
else if (eresult === Steam.EResult.AccountLogonDenied) 
{
   login.auth_code = readline.question(`[${param[0]}] Steam Guard code: `);
   client.disconnect();
   client.connect();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two factor authentication (2FA) is a principle where you're authorized to a resource by two **separate** factors. 1. something you know (login/pass) 2. something you have (a phone with a 2FA app installed, like Google Authenticator, Authy, also I think there's an app for this made by Steam).

If I understood you correctly - you want to store passwords and 2FA details in your app. Probably there's a technical way to do it, but I would not use such an app. This is a big security no-no. Better to ask users of your app to provide login/password each time, and if Steam API asks for second factor - ask the users for it.

As I seen most APIs - you could probably get a special token so the user don't have to login and provide the code each time without storing the password etc. Dig in the docs - you'll find it. (Unless you don't use any official Steam API, but it looks form the code that you probably do)

Comment: This program is actually to log into several accounts in a loop reading user name and password from a .txt document, but there is a possibility that one or maybe even multiple accounts in the .txt with a two factor authentication enabled. Now I have my program acknowledge this and prompt the question to have a user manually put this in but what I want is for my program to pull the two factor code for any account that has it enabled and automatically input the code. But thank you for you comment I never thought about attempting to find the special token for an account.

Comment: Check out this topic on OTP https://security.stackexchange.com/a/47904/18504 It looks like what you want would be possible assuming you could get your hands on the seed data (I'm no expert, but I guess this is the QR code shown to you when you set up 2FA, so in the steam accounts it's usually long gone).